# Replacement for pj_get_def?

Tags: c++, proj

I have an application that parses the output of `pj_get_def` that turns EPSG identifiers into some useful key/value pairs.

According to [the migration guide](https://proj.org/development/migration.html), the replacement is `proj_pj_info`. However, the `PJ_PROJ_INFO` I get back has an empty `definition` and the `description` is an ambiguous (if human readable) string.

Here's test code:

```cpp
#include <proj.h>

#define ACCEPT_USE_OF_DEPRECATED_PROJ_API_H
#include <proj_api.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void test_pj(int crs)
{
  auto const arg = "+init=epsg:" + std::to_string(crs);
  auto* const proj = pj_init_plus(arg.c_str());
  auto* const text = pj_get_def(proj, 0);

  std::cout << "PROJ 4\n";
  std::cout << "text: '" << text << "'\n";
}

void test_proj(int crs)
{
  auto const arg = "EPSG:" + std::to_string(crs);
  auto* const proj = proj_create(nullptr, arg.c_str());
  auto const& info = proj_pj_info(proj);

  std::cout << "PROJ 5\n";
//   std::cout << "id: '" << info.id << "'\n"; crash?
  std::cout << "definition: '" << info.definition << "'\n";
  std::cout << "description: '" << info.description << "'\n";
}

int main()
{
  test_pj(4326);
  test_proj(4326);
}
```

And here's the output:

```
PROJ 4
text: ' +init=epsg:4326 +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0'
PROJ 5
definition: ''
description: 'WGS 84'
```

What is the replacement for `pj_get_def`? How do I decompose a `PJ` into the interesting information I could get in PROJ 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the documentation is just wrong. The correct replacement isn't `proj_pj_info`, it's `proj_as_proj_string`.

There's a small caveat, however: in PROJ 4, this included the ellipsoid. In PROJ 6, it does not. If the ellipsoid is needed, an additional call to `proj_get_ellipsoid` (followed by another `proj_as_proj_string`) is required.

---

Edit: So, it turns out `proj_pj_info` *does* work... but only in PROJ 5 (not PROJ 6), and only using `+init=epsg:N` (which is not supported in PROJ 6).

I didn't dig very deeply, but I suspect that PROJ 5 doesn't support the `EPSG:N` syntax at all, making that a hard compatibility break between 5 and 6 with, apparently, no way to write code that works on both versions without resorting to version-conditional logic.